# jOOQ table template, dynamic table name for queries

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I would like to dynamically create new database tables using a predefined table template. That part I can't see any problems with.

But then I would like to have one jOOQ generated table class (from the template) to write jOOQ queries and just change the table name before executing.

Anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jOOQ's runtime schema / table mapping support for this:

```java
Settings settings = new Settings()
    .withRenderMapping(new RenderMapping()
    .withSchemata(
        new MappedSchema().withInput("THE_SCHEMA")
                          .withOutput("THE_SCHEMA")
                          .withTables(
            new MappedTable().withInput("PREDEFINED_TABLE")
                             .withOutput("CHANGED_TABLE")
        )
    ));

// Add the settings to the DSLContext
DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(connection, dialect, settings);

// Run your queries with the above ctx
ctx.select(PREDEFINED_TABLE.COLUMM)
   .from(PREDEFINED_TABLE)
   .fetch();
```

The above will generate

```sql
SELECT "THE_SCHEMA"."CHANGED_TABLE"."COLUMN"
FROM "THE_SCHEMA"."CHANGED_TABLE"
```

More info here:
http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/runtime-schema-mapping